# algebraic closure of a subgroup of GL

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $\Gamma$ be a nontrivial subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$. Then does the linear span of $\Gamma$ over $C$ have to contain the algebraic closure of $\Gamma$? Or is there some required condition in order that this statement to be true?

Comment: By linear span you mean the subspace spanned by $\Gamma$ in the vector space of matrices? By algebraic closure you mean the Zariski closure?

Comment: Let $V$ be a finitedimensional $C$-vector space and $S \subset V$ a set. Let $x$ be in the Zariski closure of $S$. By definition, each polynomial that vanishes on $S$ has to vanish at $x$. Take a linear form $f$ that vanishes on $S$. Since $f$ is a polynomial, it follows $f(x)=0$. Thus any linear form which is trivial on $S$ is trivial on the Zariski closure. Conclusion: the Zariski closure is a subset of the linear span. So the answer is yes, and has nothing to do with groups.  

Comment: If Mariano has guessed the definitions correctly, then the "linear span" of $\Gamma$ is closed and contains $\Gamma$, hence contains the Zariski closure of $\Gamma$.  The fact that $\Gamma$ is a group has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Looks like Johannes beat me to this.

Comment: But only by a second.

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore the linear span of $\Gamma$ is not contained in $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$. So you have to ask, where is it Zariski closed?